# Simple estimation question

Tags: real-analysis

I have a basic pre-analysis question for everyone. Suppose $y>1$ is some approximation to $x = \sqrt{2} + 1$. How can I show that $\frac1y+2$ is a closer approximation to $x$ than $y$ is in a rigorous way?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider $|x-(1/y+2)|=1/y|(\sqrt 2-1)y-1|=\frac{\sqrt2-1}y |\cdots|$.

Comment: I can see how you got to that point. Are you trying to show that this difference is zero? Or are we trying to show that it is less than |x-y|? I am unsure of what I am trying to show here. It seems like I can do algebra forever on this without really getting anywhere. I wonder what motivated you to look at that difference instead of trying to prove that                        |x - (1/y + 2)| is less than | x -y | ?

Comment: I think I see what you have done now, please correct me if I am wrong. I can replace ((2^(1/2)-1)/y) with 1/(xy) to obtain |x - ((1/y) + 2)|= 1/((2)^(1/2) + 1) - (1/y). Which is equivalent to [y -((2)^(1/2)+1)]/(y((2)^(1/2)+1)) = (y - x)/(yx). Then x, y greater than 1, implies |x - ((1/y) + 2)| is less than | x -y |.

Comment: You've done it! Yes, I was trying to get you to play around a bit with rearranging things, and hoping you'd spot the relationship with $1/x$ and realize that the terms pulled outside were smaller than 1. Well done!

Comment: Thank you for the hint and feedback Sharkos!